# Comparison between two int arrays results unexpected

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I'm trying to compare two chessboards (represented by `int[][]`). I've written the same algorithm in C++ too and had no issues comparing the chessboards for equality.

I'm trying to post the most relevant code here. Are there any Java fundamentals I have missed regarding comparison between 'two dimensional' Arrays? Or could it be memory/storage related because it didn't sort out the duplicates of the solutions?  I tried to allocate new memory for the chessboards in the list but this ends in a endless loop.

I also used multiple ways of comparing the boards even with .equals, .deepEquals, for each iteration and sets.

This is the code snippet from the comparison function that checks for equality and is called by the TrulyUnique Function each time I mirror and rotate. I'm comparing 2 variables of type `int[][]` called `storeCurrentBoard` and `playboard`.

```
        int [][] storeCurrentBoard;
        for(int k = 0; k < QList.size(); k++)
        {
            //isPresentinList = true;
            storeCurrentBoard = QList.get(k);

            for(int i = 0; i < playboard.length; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < playboard[i].length; j++)
                {
                    if(playboard[i][j] != storeCurrentBoard[i][j])
                    {
                        isPresentinList = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: playboard[][] is int[][] or Integer[][] ?

Comment: @Hades  playboard[][] is int[][]. for deepEquals i used Integer but the results were the same.

Comment: Is there a reason `isPresentInList = true` is commented out? Because it shouldn't be. Otherwise, once it gets set to false, it will always remain false.

Comment: Oh sorry about that i should have posted the whole function... its set to true at the beginning of the function!

Comment: That's the problem then. It should be set to true every time you enter that outer for-loop. Uncomment that `//isPresentInList = true` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `isPresentInList = true` commented out. Uncomment it. The way you have it right now, if `isPresentInList` ever gets set to `false`, it will always remain false, making it so that all your boards afterwards will always not be equal.

```
    boolean isPresentInList;
    int [][] storeCurrentBoard;
    for(int k = 0; k < QList.size(); k++)
    {
        isPresentinList = true; //This is necessary for everything to work
        storeCurrentBoard = QList.get(k);

        outer: for(int i = 0; i < playboard.length; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < playboard[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(playboard[i][j] != storeCurrentBoard[i][j])
                {
                    isPresentinList = false;
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this was really one of the problems for comparison, thank you ! But the one that caused the real issue was that one of my methods changes the playboard and in doing so caused the program to calculate the second playboard over and over again and thats why it was stuck in a endless loop!